# A question about $G_\delta$ set

Tags: real-analysis

If $E$ is a  $G_\delta$ set then $E$can be written as $E=\bigcap\limits^{\infty}_{n=1}G_n$where  $G_n$is open set and$G_{n+1}\subset G_n$.How to prove it.

Answer (score 1):

By definition, $E=\bigcap\limits^{\infty}_{n=1}E_n$ where the $E_n$ are open.  Let $G_n=\bigcap\limits^{n}_{i=1}E_i$.  This works since finite intersections of open sets are open.